# get Youtube video description on click (html.push)

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm working with the youtube api (2.0) to pull the 9 most viewed videos from a specific channel. I've got a video player and a list of thumbnails with title + thumbnail image + viewcount + description. When clicking a list-item the chosen video will load within the player. Everything's fine so far.

Now I want to add the yt-video description, but not as part of the list items (that already works fine) but next to the player. That means I have to add the 'description' value to the loadVideo function, which fires when clicking on a list-item. But it doesn't work, no matter what I try :-(

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://swfobject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

// Load Video
function loadVideo(playerUrl, autoplay) {
  swfobject.embedSWF(
      playerUrl + '&rel=1&border=0&fs=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&autoplay=' + 
      (autoplay?1:0), 'player', '450', '250', '9.0.0', false, 
      false, {allowfullscreen: 'true'});
}

// Get feed data and push thumbnails 
function showMyVideos2(data) {
  var feed = data.feed;
  var entries = feed.entry || [];
  var html = ['<ul class="videos">'];
  for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    var entry = entries[i];
    var title = entry.title.$t.substr(0, 20);
    var description = entries[i].media$group.media$description.$t.substr(0, 100);
    var thumbnailUrl = entries[i].media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url;
    var playerUrl = entries[i].media$group.media$content[0].url;
    var viewcount = entry.yt$statistics.viewCount;
    html.push('<li onclick="loadVideo(\'', playerUrl, '\', true)">',
              '<span class="titlec">', title, '...</span><br /><img src="', 
              thumbnailUrl, '" width="130" height="97"/><br /><span class="views">Views: ', viewcount,'</span><br><span class="views">', description,'</span></li>');
  }
  html.push('</ul><br style="clear: left;"/>');
  document.getElementById('videos2').innerHTML = html.join('');

  // Load first video by default
  if (entries.length > 0) {
    loadVideo(entries[0].media$group.media$content[0].url, false);
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Output -->
<div style="width:800px; margin: 0 auto;">    
<div id="playerContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 250px; float: left;"><object id="player"></object></div>
<div id="videos2"></div>        
</div>

<!-- JSON Feed -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/100stimmen/uploads?alt=json-in-script&callback=showMyVideos2&max-results=9&orderby=viewCount">
</script>
```

I think I'll have to manipulate 3 things:

1) add the 'description' value to the loadVideo function and print out the description.

2) also add the 'description' to the html.push block which defines the click event *onclick="loadVideo()"*. That for me is the biggest problem, I can't get the syntax right to pass the description value.

3) By default the first video will be loaded in the player, so I have to add the description here too, which works like so:

```
  if (entries.length > 0) {
    loadVideo(entries[0].media$group.media$content[0].url,
    entries[0].media$group.media$description.$t.substr(0, 100), 
    false
    );
  }
```

Here's also a test page: http://viniblu.de/public/youtube_test.html

Well, that's what I have so far. Has anybody an idea how to display the description of the clicked video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had something already written that was very similar, but depends on the jQuery library. Hopefully this helps and is a good starting point.

If it were me, I'd rewrite the entire loadVideo function below to only use data found within the

. For example, a span for video URL and within the CSS it would be declared to "display:none".

Full Document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Youtube API Test</title>
<style>
.wrapper {width:800px; margin:auto;}
#screen {width: 100%; height: 250px; float: left;}
#videos {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding-left : 0em;
    margin-left: 0em;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
}
#videos li {
    float: left;
    width: 130px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-right: 1.9em;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 15px
}
#videos li span {
    font: 10px/11px arial, sans-serif;
}
.cb {clear:both;}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://swfobject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    // get youtube video feed
    $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/100stimmen/uploads?alt=json&max-results=9&orderby=viewCount', function(data){
        var feed = data.feed;
        var entries = feed.entry || [];
        for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            var entry = entries[i];
            var title = entry.title.$t.substr(0, 20);
            var description = entries[i].media$group.media$description.$t.substr(0, 100);
            var thumbnailUrl = entries[i].media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url;
            var playerUrl = entries[i].media$group.media$content[0].url;
            var viewcount = entry.yt$statistics.viewCount;
            $('#videos').append('<li onclick="loadVideo(\'' + playerUrl + '\', true, ' + i + ')"><span class="titlec">' + title + '...</span><br /><img src="' + thumbnailUrl + '" width="130" height="97"/><br /><span class="views">Views: ' + viewcount + '</span><br><span class="desc">' + description + '</span></li>');
        }
    }).done(function(){
        // play first video
        $('#videos li').eq(0).click();
    });

});

// our video play function
function loadVideo(playerUrl, autoplay, index) {
    var $this = $('#videos li').eq(index);
    swfobject.embedSWF(
        playerUrl + '&rel=1&border=0&fs=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&autoplay=' + 
        (autoplay?1:0), 
        'player', 
        '450', 
        '250', 
        '9.0.0', 
        false,
        false,
        {allowfullscreen: 'true'}
    );
    $('#desc').html($this.find('.desc').html());
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="screen">
        <object id="player"></object>
    </div>
    <div id="desc"></div>
    <div>
        <ul id="videos"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cb"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE - IE didn't like the request until I updated the $.json function to use $.ajax. I made a few improvements by changing to the ajax function I was able to turn off IE's cache, and add the datatype "jsonp" which allowed IE to make the cross-domain request.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Youtube API Test</title>
<style>
.wrapper {width:800px; margin:auto;}
#screen {width: 100%; height: 250px; float: left;}
#videos {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding-left : 0em;
    margin-left: 0em;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
}
#videos li {
    float: left;
    width: 130px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-right: 1.9em;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 15px
}
#videos li span {
    font: 10px/11px arial, sans-serif;
}
.cb {clear:both;}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://swfobject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    // get youtube video feed
    $.ajax({
            url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/100stimmen/uploads?alt=json&max-results=9&orderby=viewCount",
            dataType: 'jsonp'
    }).done(function(data){
        var feed = data.feed;
        var entries = feed.entry || [];
        for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            var entry = entries[i];
            var title = entry.title.$t.substr(0, 20);
            var description = entries[i].media$group.media$description.$t.substr(0, 100);
            var thumbnailUrl = entries[i].media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url;
            var playerUrl = entries[i].media$group.media$content[0].url;
            var viewcount = entry.yt$statistics.viewCount;
            $('#videos').append('<li onclick="loadVideo(\'' + playerUrl + '\', true, ' + i + ')"><span class="titlec">' + title + '...</span><br /><img src="' + thumbnailUrl + '" width="130" height="97"/><br /><span class="views">Views: ' + viewcount + '</span><br><span class="desc">' + description + '</span></li>');
        }
        // play first video
        $('#videos li').eq(0).click();
    });

});

// our video play function
function loadVideo(playerUrl, autoplay, index) {
    var $this = $('#videos li').eq(index);
    swfobject.embedSWF(
        playerUrl + '&rel=1&border=0&fs=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&autoplay=' + 
        (autoplay?1:0), 
        'player', 
        '450', 
        '250', 
        '9.0.0', 
        false,
        false,
        {allowfullscreen: 'true'}
    );
    $('#desc').html($this.find('.desc').html());
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="screen">
        <object id="player"></object>
    </div>
    <div id="desc"></div>
    <div>
        <ul id="videos"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cb"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: This is an update to the loadVideo function which prevents autoplay.

```
function loadVideo(playerUrl, autoplay, index) {
    var $this = $('#videos li').eq(index);
    console.log((autoplay?1:0));
    swfobject.embedSWF(
        playerUrl + '&rel=1&border=0&fs=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&autoplay=0',
        'player', 
        '450', 
        '250', 
        '9.0.0', 
        false,
        false,
        {allowfullscreen: 'true'}
    );
    $('#desc').html($this.find('.desc').html());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Markus, this solution works fine in Webkit browsers and Firefox but unfortunately not in IE, even the newer ones. I've got no idea why.

Comment: I updated the code. For some reason, IE wasn't firing the request off. I assumed it was a cross-domain issue, and found that the $.ajax call was more reliable and actually worked after setting the dataType to 'jsonp'. Updated the code and saw it working in IE7/8/9/10.

Comment: veeery cool :-) one thing: I'd like to stop the first video from autoplay, what do I have to change here: $('#videos li').eq(0).click(); ?

Comment: @Alani I made an additional update to the loadVideo function. Basically you need to either set autoplay = false, or take it out all together. See example above.

Comment: thanks again! I really appreciate your help! Do you think one could use this script also with the iframe api? I tried, but it's really difficult because the method which loads the player is completely different. I might post another question on this... Thanks again, you really made my day so far :-)

Comment: Glad I could help. I'm not an expert on the iframe api, but you could use the same concept above to replace the iframe on the page with a new one? Good luck! :)